# Как в окно OpenGL загрузить картинку?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

На одном сайте с уроками по OpenGL (http://www.codenet.ru/progr/opengl/opengl_05.php) я вычитал мол:

> В OpenGL нет функций чтения/записи графических файлов. Но поддерживается работа с массивами пикселей. Вы загружаете графический файл, используя библиотеки других фирм, в память и работаете с ними средствами OpenGL.

И как я понял надо использовать сторонние библиотеки для этого?
Или в новых версия OpenGL появились такие функции?

Comment: Нет, не появились (и не появятся, это не задача OpenGL). OpenGL все еще хочет от вас массив пикселей в определенном формате.